# how to detect if you are running outside of the rails main app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I detect that code is running *outside* the main rails app?

For example in a console, or in a rake task, or as part of a scheduler action, etc.

I understand that there are specific ways to do this for each case (i.e. check `Rails::Console` etc, but I am looking for a general way to this that will work for all cases.

To clarify a bit further.  By "main rails app" I mean the "instance" of rails that is responding to http requests.

Comment: by detect you mean at runtime, retrospectively through logs, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the server is active use:

```
Rails.const_defined? 'Server'
```

Comment: Thanks... works great (at least in Rails 5) do you know if this const is also defined in Rails 4?  I assume so...